# Function that groups JSON data

Tags: javascript

I  am trying to write a function in javascript that from JSON input data returns the data belonging to a specific group, including the children of that group. The data looks like this:

```
            [
            {"id":"0", "name":"Person 0"},
            {"id":"1", "name":"Person 1","group":"0"},
            {"id":"2", "name":"Person 2","group":"0"},
            {"id":"3", "name":"Person 3","group":"2"},
            {"id":"4", "name":"Person 4","group":"2"},
            {"id":"5", "name":"Person 5","group":"4"},
            {"id":"6", "name":"Person 6","group":"4"},
            {"id":"7", "name":"Person 7","group":"0"},
            {"id":"8", "name":"Person 8","group":"7"}
            ]
```

Here, a person in group x belongs to the same group as person with id x.

For example: function(data, group) would return the following for function(data, 2):

```
            [
            {"id":"3", "name":"Person 3","group":"2"},
            {"id":"4", "name":"Person 4","group":"2"},
            {"id":"5", "name":"Person 5","group":"2"},
            {"id":"6", "name":"Person 6","group":"2"},
            ]
```

and function(data,0):

```
            [
            {"id":"1", "name":"Person 1","group":"1"},
            {"id":"2", "name":"Person 2","group":"2"},
            {"id":"3", "name":"Person 3","group":"2"},
            {"id":"4", "name":"Person 4","group":"2"},
            {"id":"5", "name":"Person 5","group":"2"},
            {"id":"6", "name":"Person 6","group":"2"},
            {"id":"7", "name":"Person 7","group":"7"},
            {"id":"8", "name":"Person 8","group":"7"}
            ]
```

I have tried to loop through the array but that doesn't deal with the subgroups, so I guess I have to do it in a recursive fashion?

Comment: "but that doesn't deal with the subgroups" --- in your examples you don't deal with subgroups as well.

Comment: @zerkms Yes he does. The subgroup refers to the ID

Comment: @Rob W: in which of 2 examples there is a recursive execution?

Comment: Yes, the group is associated with the ID. For example: sub group 4 is returned as group 2, because thats the parent group.

Comment: @zerkms The first example: Group 2 selects ID 3 and 4. Group 3 = nothing, Group 4 = id 5 and 6. I can imagine that the question is unclear though. graphmeter, can you edit your question to make the format of your expected result more obvious? Currently, we have to look at the code and find the pattern. Furthermore, what's the logic behind the renaming of the group properties?

Comment: @Rob W: Oh, that's right. What confused me is that in the result set `group` property is modified

Comment: @graphmeter you should clarify how to access a subgroup group.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. The rationale behind this questions is that I would like to plot the nodes belonging to a specific group.

Comment: @graphmeter: I updated my answer. I assumed you wanted to traverse as deeply into sub groups as possible instead of merely one level deep. If there's any chance that there could be circular references, that would need to be handled.

Comment: @user1689607: thanks! I will try it out. Yes, as deeply into the sub groups as possible is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.reduce()` the data array and concatenate in the sub groups.

```
function dataForGroup(data, group, refs) {
    if (!refs)
        refs = {};

       // check if it's in the list
    if (refs[group] === true)
        return []; // or you can throw an Error
    else
        refs[group] = true; // first encounter, so add it to the list

    return data.reduce(function(res, obj) {
        return obj.group == group ? 
                   res.concat(obj, dataForGroup(data, obj.id, refs)) : res;
    }, []);
}
```

Hopefully there are no circular references!

<s>Though I don't understand the `group(data, 0)` output, and I don't see any sub-group data.</s>

Comment: Thanks. However, I get an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, for some of the groups, e.g. 2.

Comment: @graphmeter: I don't get that for group 2. http://jsfiddle.net/Kt7Ce/ but you will need to watch for circular references.

Comment: Now I got it to work, great! What is a good way to look out for circular references?

Comment: @graphmeter: Whenever you make a call to `dataForGroup`, you would need to check a list to see if that ID is there. If not, add it to the list. If so, either return an empty Array, or throw an Error, depending on how you want to handle it. I'll give an update.

Comment: @graphmeter  for info: .reduce is not supported by IE<= 8;

Comment: @graphmeter for info: It's trivial to add a shim into `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through entire data array and filter out items with same group.

```
    var newArr = [],
    isVisted = []; // using to prevent circular reference.

function getGroup(data, groupId, inside) {
    if (!inside) {
        newArr = [];
        isVisted = [];
    }
    if (isVisted.indexOf(groupId) !== -1) {
        return
    };
    for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
        if (data[k].group == groupId) {
            newArr.push(data[k])
            getGroup(data, data[k].id, true);
        }
    }

    return newArr;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zTFbz/1/)

Comment: @Shusi Because the OP's examples show that the group-ID mapping are dynamic.

Comment: @Shusi Look closer to the question plus the discussion in the comments below to see what I mean.

Comment: @RobW I made changes based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said using javascript, I did it only with javascript. However there are more easier ways to do such a thing in jquery. I didn't test it, just wrote it, so if it was any problem do not hesitate to comment about it.

```
function Group(data)
{
    var result = [];

    for (var item in data)
    {
        var group = (item.group) ? item.group : -1;

        if (!result[group])

            result[group] = [];

        result[group].push(item);
    }

    return result;
}

var secondGroup = Group(
    [
        {"id":"0", "name":"Person 0"}, 
        {"id":"1", "name":"Person 1","group":"0"}, 
        {"id":"2", "name":"Person 2","group":"0"}, 
        {"id":"3", "name":"Person 3","group":"2"}, 
        {"id":"4", "name":"Person 4","group":"2"}, 
        {"id":"5", "name":"Person 5","group":"4"}, 
        {"id":"6", "name":"Person 6","group":"4"}, 
        {"id":"7", "name":"Person 7","group":"0"}, 
        {"id":"8", "name":"Person 8","group":"7"} 
    ]
)[2];
```

Cheers